# invalid address error on resend method

Tags: go-ethereum, web3js, parity, resend

I've connected to Parity client with `geth attach` and try to resend my transaction with resend method.

```
>web3.eth.resend("0xed2ec75fa32e19869cc740478828aa42471705d87bda87ca55cb7f71ebcf2de2", 21000000000, 21000)
Error: invalid address
    at web3.js:3930:15
    at web3.js:3756:20
    at web3.js:5025:28
    at map (<native code>)
    at web3.js:5024:12
    at web3.js:5050:18
    at web3.js:5075:23
    at <anonymous>:1:1
```

I am using Ubuntu 16.04 with Parity/v1.10.8-stable-bd20c45-20180628/x86_64-linux-gnu/rustc1.27.0.